# Pull data from reference tables (displayed in XML format) and store it in another XML file

Tags: json, xml, wordpress, csv

I want to link a reference table, (given to me in XML format via link, from a remote server) into another XML file.
For example

```
<reference>
  <listName>countries</listName> 
  <itemCount>191</itemCount> 
  <item type="Country" row="1"> 
    <id>1104</id> 
    <name>TURKEY</name> 
  </item>
</reference>    <!-- Added by edit -->
```

The thing is that every single item is in different  XML, with different link. So I need to link them all and, (in a way) filter the information in a new XML, which to  then import to Word Press.

If not XML to XML, then XML to JSON or CSV is ok. Or if there is an software to help me do this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this would be by using XSLT. Which version would be best depends on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use some online tool where you can load data from URL i found one editor you can use that or use some similar online tool.

- [Online Ide for xml to json](https://codebeautify.org/xmltojson)